# Which language was used on store billboards and newspapers in No Escape (2015)?

Tags: no-escape

Based on this question: [What country does No Escape take place in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44030/what-country-does-no-escape-take-place-in) the country is unknown and population speaks a mix of some Thai languages, what language is used in newspapers and store billboards portrayed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks laotian; https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RdiBiTPt4EU/UfYuZw7tYDI/AAAAAAAAIzA/TvGHV3XGDiA/s500/laos-vientianebussched.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Based on just a visual comparison, It's a Tai based written language, common to Thai and Lao and other languages in the region, while not being exactly either. This image was pulled from wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isan_language

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned anywhere which country they were in but I got a clue from their plane scene. I suppose its either Thailand or Vietnam.

[image: Plane scene]

[image: Original map]